# Why do we need the base-to-member idiom?

Tags: c++, inheritance, initialization

I am familiar with the base-to-member idiom, and its classic example:

```
#include <streambuf>  // for std::streambuf
#include <ostream>    // for std::ostream

namespace  std {
  class streambuf;
  class ostream {
    explicit ostream(std::streambuf * buf);
    //...
  };
}
class fdoutbuf   // A customization of streambuf
    : public std::streambuf
{
public:
    explicit fdoutbuf( int fd );
    //...
};

class fdostream
    : public std::ostream
{
protected:
    fdoutbuf buf;
public:
    explicit fdostream( int fd ) 
        : buf( fd ), std::ostream( &buf ) 
        // This is not allowed: buf can't be initialized before std::ostream.
        // std::ostream needs a std::streambuf object defined inside fdoutbuf.
    {}
};
```

I have always assumed the rule that you cannot get the address of `buf` in the constructor was part of the C++ specification.  I have recently started a project that does something similar to `&buf` in similar circumstances.  I wanted to point them to the C++ spec to show it as undefined behavior, but my search is coming up dry.

**Is is possible this is actually legal, just merely undesirable?  Or can someone please quote me the sections from the spec that I can take to the rest of the team and determine what to do about it?**

A related ticket, [this pointer to base class constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538491/this-pointer-to-base-class-constructor) covers the case of passing the `this` pointer to a base class, but that seems to be handled by different sections of the spec, such as 12.7.3

Comment: "base _from_ member", isn't it

Answer (score 6):

It's totally legal to take the address of an as-yet-uninitialized member, base, or local variable. It's if you start trying to read or write to that pointer that bad things happen. If you're merely storing the pointer for later use after initialization, that is perfectly legitimate.